# Array into json formatting

Tags: python, json, database, firebase

I am trying to format a list of cities into json to put it on a firebase database.

I am really new to coding and very lost. Working in python but just trying to get this text formatted.

My list of cities
`cities = ['Abu Dhabi', 'Albuquerque', 'Amsterdam', 'Anchorage', 'Antalya', 'Aspen', 'Athens', 'Atlanta', 'Austin', 'Bali', 'Baltimore', 'Bangalore', 'Bangkok', 'Barcelona', 'Beijing', 'Berlin', 'Berlin', 'Bogota', 'Bora Bora', 'Boston', 'Brisbane', 'Brussels', 'Buffalo', 'Burbank', 'Cairo', 'Cancun', 'Cape Town', 'Changcha', 'Charlotte', 'Chengdu', 'Chicago', 'Chongqing', 'Cincinnati']`

I need to format them like this

```
},
    "Seattle" : {
      "city_name" : "Seattle"
    },
    "Houston" : {
      "city_name" : "Houston"
    }
```

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple dict comprehension:

```
cities = ['Chicago', 'Charlotte', 'Barcelona']
print({city: {'city_name': city} for city in cities})
```

Which prints:

```
{'Chicago': {'city_name': 'Chicago'}, 'Charlotte': {'city_name': 'Charlotte'}, 'Barcelona': {'city_name': 'Barcelona'}}
```